Crash in Foundation: When storing KeyedDecodingContainer for later decoding
i'm trying to decode a json where part of it is only known at a later stage. My solution was to store the container and have it decode a property once the type is known.
struct HTTPBody: Decodable {
    let statusCode: Int

    /// The decoding container to decode the responseBody once the type is known
    private let container: KeyedDecodingContainer<CodingKeys>

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case statusCode
        case responseBody
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.statusCode = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .statusCode)
    }

    func responseBody<T: Decodable>(as decodeType: T.Type) -> T? {
        try? container.decode(T.self, forKey: .responseBody)
    }
}

Most of the time it works, but when it is not working it crashes with an exception in Foundation:
Foundation/JSONDecoder.swift:1180: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Foundation.JSONError.cannotConvertInputStringDataToUTF8(location: Foundation.JSONError.SourceLocation(line: 1, column: 131, index: 130))

The Json doesn't change between working and crashing and does not contain suspicious characters:
{
    "statusCode": 412,
    "responseBody": {
      "validationErrors": [
        {
          "message": "User account cannot be created"
        }
      ]
    }
}


I have the feeling that it may be related to storing the container for use outside of the init, but i don't know why that should be a problem.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

I don't think JSONDecoder is designed for you to store a decoding container for later use. Instead of conforming to Decodable, how about take some JSON Data in its initialiser, and keep that data instead?
